# How can I "performance detect" browsers

Tags: javascript, performance, browser, browser-detection, browser-feature-detection

Some mobile browsers and IE8 javascript is not just a little bit slower, it's many times 10x slower! There are lots of things that pass feature detection tests (js css manipulations, etc) but are so slow they degrade the user experience.

Modernizr will tell me that a feature exists, but it won't tell me if it's below some performance threshold.

Detecting IE8 would work for IE8 users, but it won't work for slow mobile devices, tablets, and computers running old versions of FF, Safari, mobile Opera, etc.

What are effective ways to temper or disable slow features without penalizing modern browser users?

Are the better methods than time-stamping code execution blocks?

Comment: @Knu, where? Have a link?

Answer (score 3):

There is no public database of performance by feature by device, nor any automated way to turn potentially slow features on and off. You'll have to decide for yourself what features you think are slow on what devices and turn them off, such as

```
body.transitions-are-slow * {
  transition-property: none !important;
}
```

Then arrange to place the `transitions-are-slow` class on the body based on some kind of device sniffing and empirical knowledge of that device's performance.

That's for CSS, but you also mention JS. However, I can't think of cases where some particular JS API is particularly slow on some particular device. JS will slow down uniformly on slower devices. Therefore, I don't really see why, or how, you would want to be thinking about turning off individual JS features based on device performance issues.

> Are there better methods than time-stamping code execution blocks?

There's no obvious way to timestamp CSS performance, but for JS I suppose you could do the following, use with care:

```
function kill_if_slower_than(fn, threshold) {
  var killed = false;
  return function() {
      if (killed) return;
      var start  = performance.now();
      var result = fn.apply(this, arguments);
      killed     = performance.now() - start > threshold;
      return result;
  };
}
```

This will return a function which will turn into a no-op the first time its execution takes longer than `threshold` milliseconds. You obviously don't want to use this on anything other than something purely optional. It also is not going to help you with asynchronous situations.

I have used `performance.now` above due to its higher resolution, however on some older browsers you might need to fall back to `Date.now()`.

Comment: Different code runs differently in different browsers under different hardware. On my computer, running `for(var x=new Date(),i=0;i++<1e4;i<<9&9%9*9+9);console.log((new Date())-x);` in IE11 shows 4-6ms, while Chrome takes 8-10ms.

Comment: That same code on a VM running Android 4.2.2 (on the default browser) takes 0-1ms to finish.

Comment: No front-end framework incorporating this kind of stuff yet? Progressively enhance with animations, with "breakpoints" based on actual measured device performance

Answer (score 1):

Even though you don't like the js tests, Modenizr.js is a confident library for doing all the css/js testing you could need.

Otherwise, testing the abilities of the actual computer is impossible without trying to poll it yourself (ie. taking time measurements during loading).

Your other option for IE. is the good 'ol HTML conditionals.

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    HTML CODE OR SCRIPTS
<![endif]-->
```

You can task PHP to dissect the User-Agent string that browsers supply to pick up browser versions, and even OS type and re-route the requests that way, or put in conditional statements in the document. There is an available lightweight library for this here...

https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect

```
<?php
require_once '../Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;
$deviceType = ($detect->isMobile() ? ($detect->isTablet() ? 'tablet' : 'phone') : 'computer');
?>
<html>
   <body>
      <script src="js/main.<?= $deviceType ?>.min.js" type="text/javascript></script>
      <script>
          <? if($deviceType==='phone') { ?>
          alert('You're on a phone!');
          <? } ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

What this code would do is detect (using the user-agent string) what kind of device it is, and then in the document it prints in the device type where the javascript file would be put in place. So a tablet user's browser would load in the js file `js/main.tablet.min.js`. I also included a small conditional example.

Comment: I'm currently using Modernizr and IE8 isn't my main problem. Many mobile browsers, for example, will pass Modernizr tests but perform so slowly that it makes many features (like various types of animations) impractical. I would like to disable those proverbial animations for just the people for whom it would degrade their experience.

Comment: It's a rough route, but you could use a PHP mobile detect script to conditionally block out code if it's mobile or not.

Comment: I should note that with that Mobile Detect library I've included the footprint is very small. Just update that library when you can so that the new devices can be supported for detection.

Comment: Mobile detecting feels impractical for this. Performance is not at all correlated with a single mobile device. It's the cross product of manufacturer, os version, browser version, and phone settings. Also given the incredible amounts of mobile fragmentation (thousands of devices) this sounds extra bad.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you have no choice but to time stamp it. There is no applicable way to judge a clients performance without either testing it, or running more code. If performance is laking in your scripts then you need to redesign or rethink what your doing.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this method:

**First**: in your HTML head section, place this code

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class="10+"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
```

**Then**, you can easily detect with a little JS function what is the current version of IE and disable some features.

```
var modern_browser = true; 
var internet_explorer_version = null; 
var detectBrowser = function() {  
    var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]; 
    if (html.className === 'notie') 
    { 
        return ; 
    } 
    internet_explorer_version = html.className; 
    modern_browser = false;
    return; 
}();

if (modern_browser === false)
{ 
    alert ("You use Internet Explorer : version " + internet_explorer_version);
}
else 
{ 
    alert ("You use a modern Browser ;-)");
}
```

**[JSBin to test](http://jsbin.com/EdekUNu/2/edit?html,js,output)**

Comment: I already have the IE version detection, but IE isn't my main problem. My main problems are super slow tablet browsers, slow computers, and a more general purpose way to tailor a good experience for everyone.